# How to remove form autofocus on a Twitter Bootstrap form

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap on a site. Bootstrap is loading via a cdn. I can't edit the code directly. How can I remove the form auto focus? When I visit the page it automatically jumps down to the bottom of the page where the form is.

Comment: Can you add a dummy input at the top of the page?

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: Better just to use JavaScript with something like: `document.querySelector('classname-of-element').autofocus = false;`

Comment: Bootstrap does not cause auto-focus by itself [on a form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/) so you have either set the autofocus attribute on the field, or some other JS is setting it.